# Why is this wildcard not working in bash?

Tags: bash, wildcards

I have an alias set up

```
alias nano="nano -B"
```

so everytime I change a `<configFile>`, a backup `<configFile>~` is generated.

Now I have a lot of those backups I don't need anymore so I tried

```
rm *~
```

but this doesn't work

```
rm: cannot remove '*~': No such file or directory
```

**How can I remove all files ending with `~`?**

EDIT: 
here the ouput of `ls -alF` (in this case I'm `root` and in the `/root` folder)

```
drwx------  6 root root  4096 Nov  9 12:58 ./
drwxr-xr-x 23 root root  4096 Oct 31 06:55 ../
-rw-------  1 root root 51486 Nov  9 11:13 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  4218 Nov  9 12:56 .bashrc
drwx------  2 root root  4096 Jul 19 15:47 .cache/
drwx------  2 root root  4096 Jun 27 15:36 .gnupg/
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Jul  3 10:54 .nano/
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   798 Jun 27 11:45 .profile
-rw-------  1 root root  1024 Jun 27 14:25 .rnd
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    66 Sep  4 14:15 .selected_editor
drwx------  2 root root  4096 Sep  5 13:00 .ssh/
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    65 Nov  9 09:30 Trying
-rw-------  1 root root   628 Jul 19 15:37 .viminfo
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   143 Nov  9 12:58 .virtualMachines
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   143 Nov  9 12:58 .virtualMachines~
-rw-rw-r--  1 root root   358 Nov  9 12:57 .virtualServices
-rw-rw-r--  1 root root   358 Nov  9 09:48 .virtualServices~
```

in this case I want to remove `.virtualMachines~` and `.virtualServices~`

Comment: for me it works. Are you sure that you're in the folder where these files exist? please add output of ls -l. I have the same error when no file like that exists.

Comment: Oh, for me too – you seem to be in the wrong directory.

Comment: No I'm definatly not see the edit. Is it a problem they start with a `.`?

Comment: Files and directories starting `.` are usually "hidden", the default globbing excludes those. See dupe on matching them correctly. (I'd personally use `shopt -s dotglob`)

Comment: @muru can you anyway explain please how this works in general? Tha answer of your link doesn't realy explain how to setup a custom extglob. Or does it mean after you did `shopt -s extglob` you can use it as pattern in the command line? (woulda be ugly to have to remind this pattern everytime)

Comment: @derHugo the latter, and that's why I prefer `dotglob`.